# Deriving recursive definition from function specification

Tags: proof-techniques, recursion, induction, calculus-of-constructions

Given this function specification, where name `xs` is bound to a list, `#` denotes its cardinality and `.` is the `list index` operator...

$$\left( \sum i: 0 \leq i < \#xs: xs.i * (i + 1) \right)$$

I need to derive a recursive function using induction.

Base case: `[]`

\begin{align}
 \left( \sum i: 0 \leq i < \#[]: xs.i * (i + 1) \right) && \text{(Textual substitution - xs is free)} \\
 \left( \sum i: 0 \leq i < 0: xs.i * (i + 1) \right) && \text{(Def. of #)} \\
 \left( \sum i: False: xs.i * (i + 1) \right) && \text{(Algebra)} \\
 \left( \sum i: 0 \leq i < \#xs: xs.i * (i + 1) \right) && \text{(Empty range)} 
\end{align}

Inductive case: `(x:xs)`

\begin{align}
  \left( \sum i: 0 \leq i < \#(x:xs): (x:xs).i * (i + 1) \right) && \text{(Textual substitution - xs is free)} \\
  \left( \sum i: 0 \leq i < 1 + \#xs: (x:xs).i * (i + 1) \right) && \text{(Def. of #)}
\end{align}

How can I proceed from here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notation and understanding are pretty good.

It is easier to consider `(xs:x)` as the inductive case instead of `(x:xs)`

\begin{align}
\sum_{i:\ 0 \leq i < \#(xs:x)} &(xs:x).i * (i + 1)\\
&=\sum _{i:\ 0 \leq i < \#xs+1} (x:xs).i * (i + 1) \\
&=\sum_{i:\ 0 \leq i < \#xs} (xs:x).i * (i + 1)+\sum_{i:\ i=\#xs}(xs:x).i * (i + 1)\\
&=\sum_{i:\ 0 \leq i < \#xs} xs.i * (i + 1)+x*(\#xs+1),\\
\end{align}
where we assume that list index starts with 0.

If we denote the function by $f$, the above equality becomes 
$$ f(xs:x) = f(xs) + x*(\#xs+1), $$
which is the recursive step of a recursive definition.

The base case, as you have indicated, is 
$$ f([]) =  \sum_{ i:\ 0 \leq i < 0} [].i * (i + 1)  =  \sum_{i: \text{ empty set}}[].i * (i + 1) =0.$$

---

**Exercise**. Derive the following recursive formula of the same function $f$.
$$ f(x:xs) = f(xs) + t(xs)+ x, $$
where $$t(xs)=\sum_{i:\ 0 \leq i < \#(xs)} xs.i,$$
the sum of items in $xs$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I only have `cons` (x:xs) operator in my list of definitions (it takes as first parameter a single item). I appreciate the exercise. Will try to do it.

Comment: Could you give me a hint on your exercise? Do I need to find `f`?

Comment: Thank you. I checked and I think it is an exact replica of this answer. Perhaps I am missing something ?

Comment: Thank you, @Apass.Jack. I liked your solution, but as I said, I am only allowed to prove using `(x:xs)` pattern. I cannot switch the order of list and single item as in `(xs:x)`. But it was of great help. One question, how does one use those posts with "overlaps". Is there a button to "reveal", or it is only a demonstration?

Comment: @F.Zer, that last part contains an answer that only uses $(x:xs)$. No $(xs:x)$. However, it is not easy to visualize since it is in latex/mathjax source. Well, I copied and pasted [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4447/580448) for you to double check.

Comment: @F.Zer, please click the link labelled "edited Dec 16 at 4:25" right under my answer above. You will see three links labelled "source", "edit" and "link" respectively for each version. Click the top "source" button. Then you can see the source of my answer. Note that the last part is surrounded by "<!--" and "-->", an html comment-out mechanism which hides the last part at the time of rendering. That is why you cannot see that part right here, although it has been included in the source of the last version of answer. That hiding technique seems an unpublished editing technique here.

Comment: I now managed to see full LaTeX code and accepted the answer because it solves the problem.